# Gravatar email hash function

Tags: php, gravatar

Let's say my email is `test@test.com`, I am registered with Gravatar.com and I have defined a custom image.

Now, when I try and follow the instructions that appear on gravatar.com and do this:

```
$gravatar = md5( strtolower( trim( $user->email ) ) );

<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<?= $gravatar ?>?s=100" />
```

I don't get the default gravatar image, so that means there's something wrong with the email address I entered.

But when I remove the `strtolower` and the `trim` functions, everything is working perfectly.

**Note: $user->email = test@test.com (no trailing spaces or capitals anywhere).**

Why is that? also, if I echo $gravatar with the `strtolower` and `trim` functions, it looks exactly the same.

Comment: Link to the instructions on gravatar.com

Comment: @trojanfoe http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/

Comment: if I echo both strings, once with the strtolower and trim and once without, they look the same, but the md5 hash is different.

Comment: Your code looks good - are you sure $user and $user->email are valid?

Comment: Not sure what was the problem, it generates the same hash now. didn't before. Maybe I had a misspell somewhere, thanks anyways guys

Comment: @Or W, suggest you paste your "Not sure" message as an answer and accept it :) so it is removed from the 'unanswered' section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what was the problem, it generates the same hash now. didn't before. Maybe I had a misspell somewhere, thanks anyways guys